# How to show a view or widget by launch time

Tags: java, android, dialog

Can anyone help me how to show a view by launch time...I'm creating an android app and now I want to show a Dialog when user lauch the app for 3  or 4 or 5 times  to ask for rate the App. Sorry for no code snippet. Please don't tell me to use RateThisApp library. BTW l'm new to android also in sof.  Thanks...

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to be rude, but did you make any google search before writing this question? I know that you're new here, but I did a google search and I found the answer on the second link.

Answer (score 0):

At every run your Activity, you load and save counter of launches in `SharedPrererence`, if this count equals 5, you show dialog (`AlertDialog` for example)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SharedPreferences` to know how many times user open the app and make dialog depend on 3 , 4 or 5 times
if you want make it dynamic you should connect to webservice and get something unique from device like imei or bluetooth mac address to know which device run app for how many times

Comment: but I'm very new to Andriod. please can you give me some code.

Answer (score 0):

At first make sharedpreferences

```
SharedPreferences shardepreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_KEY_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Get editor

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shardepreferences.edit();
```

and now you can put String, Boolean, int, long and ... like the code below

```
editor.putLong(key, value);
if (editor.commit()) {
    //Saved Successfully
} else {
    //Does not save
}
```

key is String and value is depend on what to put
and to get values you can do like this

```
long value = shardepreferences.getLong(key, 0);
```

if the stored preferences not found or not exists 0 will return

you can change 0 with your number

Comment: what is 'key' ?...how to add it.

Comment: key is string value and used for accessing value for example

editor.putInt("counter", 10);

sharedpreferences.getInt("counter", 0);